# Why would a Leasing Agency, as Agent of the Landlords, form 4 shell corporations to be the Landlord — but with the same address?

Tags: lease, hong-kong

One of my children leases in Hong Kong. She quotes from her Tenancy Agreement

> 1. The Landlords
>
> Name : Dekker Investment Limited
> Dillinger Investment Limited
> Easeluck Development Limited
> Jekyll Investment Limited
>
> **Registered Office  : 72-76/F, Two International Finance Centre, 8 Finance Street, Central, Hong Kong. [Emboldening mine.]**
>
> 2. Agent of the Landlords
>
> Name : Henderson Leasing Agency Limited
>
> **Registered Office : 72-76/F, Two International Finance Centre,
> 8 Finance Street, Central, Hong Kong.**

A;;  their addresses are the same. So Henderson isn't trying to hide that they share the same office as the "Landlords"! But [this isn't simply a legal address](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/9wpesf/til_in_delaware_a_small_building_is_the_legal/e9n4mvk/) for a registered agent! My child visited one of these Floors before, and personally knows some employees with Henderson. They confirm that Floors 72-76 house many employees and offices.

When I Googled the 4 limited corporations, I found no websites or information for a functioning bona fide (Is this the correct term?) company. Thus I think these 4 landlords are merely Shell or Holding Corporations.

**Question 1.** But why wouldn't Henderson Leasing Agency Limited simply double as the Landlords? Why would they set up separate corporations as the Landlords?

**Question 2.** Why would Henderson need to set up 4 separate corporations Why not just 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property probably has four co-owners who provided capital for the project but want to be protected beyond their investment from landlord-liability for a property managed by a third-party management company, which probably has no ownership interest in the property.

I see that structure a lot in U.S. real estate investments.

There may be tax laws that make co-ownership by four corporations more favorable than having four co-owners in one company serving as a landlord.

Comment: @asts Fixed. Writing faster than I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

### Why do you think they have the same shareholders?

There’s no reason to believe that they are related corporations just because they share an address.

I am shareholder and director of 4 corporations. 3 have the same shareholders in the same proportion. The other has different shareholders. All of them have their registered office at my accountant’s premises. It’s a small suburban practice so there are probably only a few hundred companies at that address. A large city practice would have thousands or tens of thousands.

The property management company probably provides the same service.

Comment: I didn't even think they have the same shareholders. I do not know anything about corporate law to think anything! "3 have the same shareholders in the same proportion. " Then why have the 3? The 3 feel redundant. Why not unite them?

Comment: @asts because they operate different businesses

Comment: Why not unite them into 1 holding corporation, then use 3 different Trade Names to represent them as different businesses?

Comment: @asts because then if one went bust they’d all go bust